# Change of coordinates vs change of shape

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions, coordinate-systems, cylindrical-coordinates

It is an elementary fact that we are able to change coordinates system to new one. for example in Cartesian coordinates $x^2+y^2=1$ illustrates a circle. Changing to polar coordinates, this equation becomes $r^2=1$ with the same graph.

But the graph of $z=x^3-3xy^2$ in Cartesian coordinates and Cylindrical coordinates seems to be different?!

$(x,y,z): z=x^3-3xy^2$: [see its graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot%20x%5E3-3xy%5E2)

$(t,r,w): w=r^3\sin(t)(-3+4\sin^2(t))$: [see its graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cylindrical++plot+r%5E3*sin(t)*(-3%2B4sin%5E2(t)))

What's wrong? Am I misunderstanding the concept of coordinates?

Comment: I get $x^3-3xy^3=r^3\cos t(\cos^2t-3r\sin^3t)$.

Comment: Ohh. I have a typo in my question. I'll fix it.

Comment: Its not important that $x=r\sin(t)$ or $x=r\cos(t)$.

Comment: @C.F.G It is important. Besides that, Wolfram is not graphing you input in cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: So, How to plot this in Cylindrical coordinates? I think It is not important. The resulting graph must be equal ( $(t,r,w): w=r^3\cos(t)(-3+4\cos^2(t))$).

Comment: @WilliamElliot, Why the transformation is wrong? what is the correct one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed the surface should be the same regardless of the choice of coordinates. In particular, [setting $x = r \cos t$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3D+Parametric+Plot+%5B%7B+r*Cos@t,+r*Sin@t,++++r%5E3*Cos%5Bt%5D*+(Cos@t+-+3*Sin%5Bt%5D%5E2)%7D,+%7Br,+0,+1%7D,+%7Bt,+0,+2+Pi%7D+%5D) as more commonly done, or [alternatively $x = \sin t$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3D+Parametric+Plot+%5B%7B+r*Sin@t,+r*Cos@t,++++r%5E3*Sin%5Bt%5D*+(Sin@t+-+3*Cos%5Bt%5D%5E2)%7D,+%7Br,+0,+1%7D,+%7Bt,+0,+2+Pi%7D+%5D) necessarily yield the same result.

Programming-wise, there's so built-in cylindrical plot in Wolfram, as they do it in the more general [PareametricPlot3D](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricPlot3D.html).

What matters is to have the correct expression for the height of the surface accordingly (be it called $z$ or $w$).

For $\{x, y \} = \{r \cos t, r \sin t\}$, we have the height $z = r^3 \cos t \left( \cos^2 t - 3 \sin^2 t \right)$

For $\{x, y \} = \{r \sin t, r \cos t\}$, we have the height $w = r^3 \sin t \left( \sin^2 t - 3 \cos^2 t \right)$

The expression in the question post is a [different surface](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3D+Parametric+Plot+%5B%7B+r*Sin@t,+r*Cos@t,++++r%5E3*Sin%5Bt%5D*+(-3+%2B+4*Sin%5Bt%5D%5E2)%7D,+%7Br,+0,+1%7D,+%7Bt,+0,+2+Pi%7D+%5D) and cannot be obtained via trigonometric substitution of any kind.  (no matter how you swap the coordinates: [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3D+Parametric+Plot+%5B%7B+r*Cos@t,+r*Sin@t,++++r%5E3*Sin%5Bt%5D*+(-3+%2B+4*Sin%5Bt%5D%5E2)%7D,+%7Br,+0,+1%7D,+%7Bt,+0,+2+Pi%7D+%5D), or [that](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=3D+Parametric+Plot+%5B%7B+r*Cos@t,+r*Sin@t,++++r%5E3*Cos%5Bt%5D*+(-3+%2B+4*Cos%5Bt%5D%5E2)%7D,+%7Br,+0,+1%7D,+%7Bt,+0,+2+Pi%7D+%5D))